# Call class' function inside static array of class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the onClickItem function down to the Card component as a prop, so that when it is clicked the state in the current component is updated.

```
class CurrentComponent extends Component {
...

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClickItem = this.onClickItem.bind(this);

...

onClickItem() {
    this.setState({something: true});
}
static cards = [
    { position: 8, element: <Card position={8} onItemClick={this.onClickitem}/> }
];
render() {
    ...
}
```

The this inside the static array is undefined. I was wondering how I can pass the function down. It is possible to move the array declaration inside the render, but I do not want it initialized every time the component renders. Any insight appreciated!

Comment: If you want to save cpu cycles (you really shouldn't), make it a normal var and initialize in the constructor.

Comment: when using react you pretty much only want to store you're data (cards) in your state. "this" is undefined because of the static key

Answer (score 0):

take the keyword "static" off the array declaration and it will work fine.

to understand the reason why it works without static and understand how static is treated in general you can look at this code -> transpiled on right

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20context%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somethingelse%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testing%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.somethingelse%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20contex2t%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somethingelse%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20testing%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.somethingelse%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D